# JIRA reports SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 mail from address must be same as authorization user

Tags: jira

I'm using JIRA version 7.2.7, configed with progreSQL.

everything went well until I invite other users.

admin user is A@mycompany.com, outgoing email is jira@mycompany.com which is not a user of our jira system.

I logged in with A@mycompany.com, then goto outgoing setting page, "Send a Test Email" to myself, it succeeded, and I can receive that email.

but when I went to "User management", click "Invite users", filled in another email address, click "Invite users". Then the mail will never sent successfully.
and the log said:

````

```
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 mail from address must be same as authorization user
;
nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 mail from address must be same as authorization user

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2267)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1257)
    at com.atlassian.mail.server.impl.SMTPMailServerImpl.sendMimeMessage(SMTPMailServerImpl.java:245)
    at com.atlassian.mail.server.managers.EventAwareSMTPMailServer.sendMimeMessage(EventAwareSMTPMailServer.java:25)
    at com.atlassian.mail.server.impl.SMTPMailServerImpl.sendWithMessageId(SMTPMailServerImpl.java:187)
    ... 26 more
```

````

Then I created another user which is "jira@mycompany.com" (same as the Outgoing Email) and logged in with it, and then invite user again, the email got sent.

### and: we have an old version of jira 6.3.x, which has the same configuration but inviting users works well.

Any way to fix the problem? why can't we invite users with user logged in other than "jira@mycompany.com"?

Thanks very much

Comment: I tried v7.2.9, got another error:


````
com.atlassian.mail.MailException: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 Envolope sender mismatch with login user..
````


Is it possible to set all the "from" field to the default outgoing email address???

Answer (score 1):

I think this error is thrown from your SMTP server. It seems to be configured, that the "From" Mailaddress needs to be same as the the user who authenticates to the SMTP Server.

You authenticated with "jira@..." on your SMTP server, but you are trying to use "A@..." as "From" address.

You should configure your SMTP server to allow that the "From" Address differs from the authenticated user.

Comment: Thanks @wtfzn, sorry I forget to mention one thing that there is also an old server (version 6.3.x) in our company, has the same configuration, but I can invite others successfully.

so very confused.